# How function declared __declspec(naked) stores local variables?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++

```
__declspec(naked) void printfive() {
   int i = 5;
   printf("%i\n", i);
}
```

for some reason this code works, but I do not understand where the `i` is stored? In the frame of the calling function? It becomes global variable? If it is stored in the caller's frame, then how compiler knows the displacement, because you can call `printfive()` from different functions with different frame size and local variables. If it is global, or something like `static` maybe, I have tried to go recursive and I can see that variable is not changed, it is not truly local indeed. But that's obvious, there is no entry code (prolog). Ok, I understand, no prolog, no frame, no register change, but this is values, but what happens to the *scope*? Is the behaviour of this specifier defined in any reference? Is this part of C++ standard anyway? This sort of functions are great if you mostly use `asm {}` inside them, (or use asm to call them and want to be sure the function is not over optimized), but you can mix with C++. But this is sort of brain twister.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: "Is this part of C++ standard anyway?" No. What are you actually trying to achieve? What is your goal? Why are you wishing to write a function with no prolog/epilog?

Comment: I am implementing a forth-like threaded code language, each primitive is an assembler or C function. mostly asm, but sometimes C code is much simpler to read, naked functions are not screwing registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From gcc manual:

> Use this attribute ... to indicate that the specified function does
>   not need prologue/epilogue sequences generated by the compiler. It is
>   up to the programmer to provide these sequences. The only statements
>   that can be safely included in naked functions are asm statements that
>   do not have operands. All other statements, including declarations of
>   local variables, if statements, and so forth, should be avoided. Naked
>   functions should be used to implement the body of an assembly
>   function, while allowing the compiler to construct the requisite
>   function declaration for the assembler.

And it isn't standard (as well as *any* `__declspec` or `__attribute__`)

Comment: Yes, noone guarantees that it will work if you use something 'bad'. I believe it will depend on actual CPU architecture/ABI. Just stick with safe asm.

Comment: @exebook: It works in precisely this case. But have you checked that the stack frame of your caller is still intact? Its local variables, return addresses, exception handling stuff?

Answer (score 3):

I know this topic is more than several years old, Here are my own answers.

Since no references are made to Microsoft documentation regarding this topic, for those who care to learn more about what is needed or not as stated by Keltar, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/rules-and-limitations-for-naked-functions?view=vs-2019) is the Microsoft documentation that explains most of what Keltar didn't explain here.

According to Microsoft documentation, and should be avoided.

> The following rules and limitations apply to naked functions:
>
> - The return statement is not permitted.
> - Structured Exception Handling and C++ Exception Handling constructs    are not permitted because they must unwind across the stack frame.
> - For the same reason, any form of setjmp is prohibited
> - Use of the _alloca function is prohibited.
> - To ensure that no initialization code for local variables appears    before the prolog sequence, initialized local variables are not
>     permitted at function scope. In particular, the declaration of C++
>     objects are not permitted at function scope. There may, however, be
>     initialized data in a nested scope.
> - Frame pointer optimization (the /Oy compiler option) is not    recommended, but it is automatically suppressed for a naked function.
> - You cannot declare C++ class objects at the function lexical scope.    You can, however, declare objects in a nested block.

Answer (score 0):

When entering or exiting a function, the compiler adds code to help with the passing or parameters. When a function is declared naked, non of the parameter variables assignment code is generated, if you want to get at any of the parameters, you will need to directly access the relevant registers or stack (depending on the ABI defined calling convention).

In your case, you are not passing parameters to the function, therefore your code works even though the function is declared naked. Take a look at the dis-assembler if you want to see the difference.